# Background Image differs in portrait & landscape mode

Tags: android, image, landscape-portrait

I have a Background image which displayed properly on portrait but it gets stretched out in landscape.

**Portrait**:

[image]

**Landscape**:

[image]

How could I get rid of this odd view

**EDIT:**

After suggestions I've added 2 folders.

1.layout-land

2.drawable land

I've tried using same image, 9-patch images, mdpi, hdpi n all..still issue persists

[image]

Comment: Have you created a `layout-land` folder and your xml file in it?

Comment: nope @PiyushGupta am using android studio...where i should create this folder and what will be the content

Comment: @PiyushGupta now I've added the folder but still it is  giving stretched image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your image size may not be wide enough to fit in a landscape mode. For this you'll need a separate image to fit in landscape mode.

Secondly you may try creating a landscape layout which will be triggered on landscape mode.

Check the following links for more information.

[Supporting Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

[Supporting Different Densities](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)

Comment: I've created another image which has a stretched background..So that girl fits at centre of the image..And I've copied the xml code to `layout-land` folder.there I've changed the background image to new one